# Do something when the audio source has been playing for 2 mins

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I've got a script working that blends one skybox into another. I need to write some code so that this blend animation happens when the audiosource is at 2 minutes.

How can I do this?
I've read about AudioSource.timeSamples, but I don't really understand how I know when 2 minutes is reached.  Should I use some other method?

Comment: note - never use timeSamples for any reason, it is irrelevant.  you are simply thinking of **.time**.  However, honestly, it is tremendously simpler to just do what it says in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Start()
  {
  Debug.Log("Audio begins now.....");
  Invoke("TwoMinutesHasPassed", 120f);
  }

void TwoMinutesHasPassed()
  {
  Debug.Log("two minutes has passed");
  Debug.Log("now i will fade the background");
  StartCoroutine("FadeNow");
  }

private IEnumerator FadeNow()
  {
  tParam = 0f;
  while (tParam < 1)
    {
    tParam += Time.deltaTime * speed;  
    valToBeLerped = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, tParam);
    Debug.Log("valToBeLerped is " + valToBeLerped.ToString("f4"));
    yield return null;
    }
  skyboxmaterial.SetFloat("_Blend", valToBeLerped);
  Debug.Log("fade is done.");
  }
```

Comment: ah just looked up how to use Invoke. this is perfect, thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you for your help, okay it is making the skybox change but it isn't fading it, it just changes. Any ideas?

Comment: could be "speed" is set too high or low

Comment: notice the debug statement I added in the loop, that will help see what is going on

Comment: Got this error: ".FadeNow(): not all code paths return a value" so I added a "yield return null" and that got it running. Still not fading though, it  just changed from to the final sky straight away.

Comment: The debug shows it does increase the "_blend" value. So either it's doing it really quickly or its only showing once it reaches 1.

Comment: Got it working, posted it in answer. Thanks so much for your help, you are an absolute hero!

Comment: @Night.owl i am so silly, sorry!! where you have yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f); it is actually just **yield return null**.  That means, wait for **one frame**.  I am so sorry!  you should make the change in yoru production code!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class animateSkyBox : MonoBehaviour {

public Skybox sky;
public Material skyboxmaterial; 
float tParam = 0f;
float valToBeLerped = 0f;
float speed = 0.1f; 



    void Start()
  {
        skyboxmaterial.SetFloat("_Blend", 0);
  Debug.Log("Audio begins now.....");
  Invoke("TwoMinutesHasPassed", 10f);
  }

void TwoMinutesHasPassed()
  {
  Debug.Log("two minutes has passed");
  Debug.Log("now i will fade the background");
  StartCoroutine("FadeNow");
  }

private IEnumerator FadeNow()
  {
  tParam = 0f;
  while (tParam < 1)
    {
    tParam +=  Time.deltaTime;  
    valToBeLerped = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, tParam);
            skyboxmaterial.SetFloat("_Blend", valToBeLerped);
            yield return null;
    Debug.Log("valToBeLerped is " + valToBeLerped.ToString("f4"));

    }
  //skyboxmaterial.SetFloat("_Blend", valToBeLerped);
  Debug.Log("fade is done.");
  yield break;
  }

  }
```