# SmoothDamp only works in Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the yes condition inside MethodeOne is met, I want to `SmoothDamp`. But`SmoothDamp` only works in `void Update()` What should I do? Can someone offer an alternative?

```
public Transform target;
public float smoothTime = 0.3F;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

private void MethodOne()
{
    if(yes)
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = target.TransformPoint(new Vector3(0, 5, -10));
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime); 
        //SmoothDamp works only in Update()
    }
}
```

Comment: one of millions of examples of a coroutine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36408732/294884

Answer (score 0):

[Vector3.SmoothDamp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html) is a method that is meant to work over time, instead of all in one frame.
Methods such as this have to be used in something that is called more than once. Update() is called once per frame, as is a bunch of other methods.

You can put the call to MethodOne() inside of Update().

If you do not want to use Update(), you can write a [Coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) with a while loop and a yield. Then call the desired method (SmoothDamp) inside of that.
I suggest reading up on [Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html), [StartCoroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html), and [StopCoroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html). Finally, if you do this remember to yield inside of your loop! Without the yield, your game will hang.